# nginx rewriting url based on substring

Tags: nginx, wordpress, url

I have a php script that relies on reading the url to perform it's necessary actions, so I need to redirect the users coming to

`example.com/pl/[User-id-or-name]` to `example.com/pl.php/[User-id-or-name]`

I was doing that with a simple .htaccess rule

```
Options +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
RewriteRule ^pl/?$ lp.php [NC]
```

And tried doing the same thing in nginx by using

```
location ^//pl//?$ {
    rewrite ^//pl//?$ /pl.php;
}
```

It sort of works, if I go to `mydomain.com/pl/`
Then it shows me the `pl.php` file just fine, but if I add an user ID or name, then it redirects me to a Wordpress *"page not found"* page.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the double slashes are not needed. The regexp `^/pl/?$` will only match `/pl` and `/pl/`.

You can fix this by simply correcting the expression in the `location` and fixing the `rewrite`.

```
location ~ ^/pl(/.*)$ {
    rewrite ^/pl(/.*)$ /pl.php$1 break;
    return 403;
}
```

A better alternative requiring less configuration is to put the rewrite in the `server` block.

```
server {
    [...]
    rewrite ^/pl(/.*)$ /pl.php$1 last;
    [...]
}
```

See: https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html

Answer (score 0):

Why two slashes instead of one ? Plus, you're using a regexp-syntax in non-regexp-location, that's why it "sort of" works. Finally, you're missing a rewrite for virtual paths.

Considering all of the above, I would try using the following location block:

```
location / {
    if (!-e $request_filename) {
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /pl.php;
    }
}
```

Comment: I get this error with your block<br>
nginx: [emerg] duplicate location "/"<br>

Comment: Yup, thats exactly what happens when all you're doing is pasting.

Comment: Sorry about that man, I was really sleepy yesterday

Comment: This is terribly inefficient. `try_files` should be used instead. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20016461/3970218

Comment: It's the `try_files` that is terribly inefficient. Furthermore, that is s clear example of the approach "zomg, I have no idea what us my dirrecrory/files layout, so try just everything".

Answer (score 0):

This is how I fixed the problem
`rewrite ^/pl/(.*)$ /pl.php?user=$1 last;`

Yep, just this one simple rule, got it from
https://www.nginx.com/blog/creating-nginx-rewrite-rules/